# Testing GWT app using Selenium 2

Tags: gwt, selenium

I'm trying to test a button click using Selenium.
My first page has a button with ID = HOME_START_BUTTON.
When I click this my app then goes to a page with a button with an ID = CONTACTS_ADD_BUTTON.
Here is the code I have to test this.

```
private static boolean checkPageContainsStartButton()
{
    // type search query
    // driver.findElement(By.name("q")).sendKeys("qa automation\n");

    //Use static finals for these button names
    WebElement startButton = driver.findElement(By.id("HOME_START_BTN"));
    if (startButton == null)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        startButton.click();
    }

    WebElement myDynamicElement = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 30))
      .until(new ExpectedCondition<WebElement>(){
            @Override
            public WebElement apply(WebDriver d) {
            return d.findElement(By.id("CONTACTS_ADD_BTN"));
    }});

    WebElement addButton = driver.findElement(By.id("CONTACTS_ADD_BTN"));
}
```

Error stack trace

```
Command duration or timeout: 28 milliseconds
For documentation on this error, please visit: http://seleniumhq.org/exceptions/no_such_element.html
Build info: version: '2.29.0', revision: '58258c3', time: '2013-01-17 22:47:00'
System info: os.name: 'Windows 7', os.arch: 'x86', os.version: '6.1', java.version: '1.7.0_04'
Session ID: b25e7efb428c98da880826fbf9e68de6
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
Capabilities [{platform=XP, chrome.chromedriverVersion=26.0.1383.0, acceptSslCerts=false, javascriptEnabled=true, browserName=chrome, rotatable=false, locationContextEnabled=false, version=24.0.1312.57, cssSelectorsEnabled=true, databaseEnabled=false, handlesAlerts=true, browserConnectionEnabled=false, nativeEvents=true, webStorageEnabled=true, applicationCacheEnabled=false, takesScreenshot=true}]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:187)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:145)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:533)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:302)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElementById(RemoteWebDriver.java:331)
    at org.openqa.selenium.By$ById.findElement(By.java:216)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.findElement(RemoteWebDriver.java:294)
    at WebDriverTestClass.checkPageContainsStartButton(WebDriverTestClass.java:67)
    at WebDriverTestClass.main(WebDriverTestClass.java:35)
Test failed.
```

My test passes if I comment out

```
WebElement addButton = driver.findElement(By.id("CONTACTS_ADD_BTN"));
```

So basically Selenium does not appear to be able to see the new widgets on the browser window when I do a button click

Comment: Hey SSR,  Yes that was it, I'd accept your suggestion as an answer but can't as it is only a comment.

Comment: It would be nice if you can close the question after selecting the answer :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a wait till the first button action is done. Use a default constant across all waits in your app. DEFAULT_RPC_WAIT, DEFAULT_SCREEN_WAIT etc. It would help to know where you have set up your waits by using Constants instead of just magic numbers.

Also reference GWT guidelines w.r.t to Selenium - https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideTestingRemoteTesting

Answer (score 0):

1. you post that `ID = HOME_START_BUTTON`
   but in your code I see: `By.id("HOME_START_BTN")`
2. from WebDriver interface comments for findElement method:
   `findElement` should not be used to look for non-present elements, use `findElements(By)` and assert zero length response instead.

   ```
   /**
    * Find the first {@link WebElement} using the given method.
    * This method is affected by the 'implicit wait' times in force at the time of execution.
    * The findElement(..) invocation will return a matching row, or try again repeatedly until 
    * the configured timeout is reached.
    *
    * findElement should not be used to look for non-present elements, use {@link #findElements(By)}
    * and assert zero length response instead.
    *
    * @param by The locating mechanism
    * @return The first matching element on the current page
    * @throws NoSuchElementException If no matching elements are found
    * @see org.openqa.selenium.By
    * @see org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver.Timeouts
    */
   WebElement findElement(By by);
   ```